# Scroll UINavigationBar on push and scrolling pop

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

What's the best approach to make UINavigationBar scroll just like other elements in the UIViewController on push or swipe gesture back when using a UINavigationController ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A UINavigationController subclass that supports pop-interactive UINavigationbar with hidden or show.

See this Library: [KDInteractiveNavigationController](https://github.com/kingiol/KDInteractiveNavigationController)

From iOS 8 and above, to scroll the UINavigationBar, use the following:

**Swift:**

```
class YourViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
    }
}
```

For more details [click here](https://www.natashatherobot.com/navigation-bar-interactions-ios8/)

Comment: It's not what I mean... I mean animations on segue and swipe back!

Comment: If you're using UINavigationController, this is the best way, used in many apps. Yes, Basically it hides when you scroll up and shows(navigationBar) when you scroll down.

Comment: Thank you but I know some apps doing it a way that new ViewController scrolls on previous UIViewController completely, like it's another page on previous page even on swipe scrolling pop?

Comment: May be you need this: https://github.com/kingiol/KDInteractiveNavigationController

Comment: Yeah, exactly what I wanted, why don't you post it so I can confirm it's the right answer? Thank you. :)

Comment: Added, Happy Coding :)